# ios objective c dependencies error

Tags: ios, objective-c

can anyone know this error and help me to fix it,

> The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set
>   to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be
>   set in the build settings editor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgBD1.png)

Comment: Project ► (Select Your Project Target) ► Build Settings ► (Type 'swift' in Searchbar) Swift Compiler Language ► Swift Language Version ► Click on Language list to open it.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to find swift compiler in the project as requested.

Comment: Please note I am using ios objective c project, but I don't know why this option not showing in my project.

Comment: if are you using ios objective c project then this option don't showing.

Comment: hi thanks, i found it , now the issue is fixed thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Target -> Build Settings - **Swift Compiler - Language section** select version of Swift Language Version. As shown in picture[image]

Comment: Hi Aleem,
i am not able to find swift compiler in the project as requested.

Comment: hi thanks, i found it , now the issue is fixed thanks

Comment: great to hear, kindly upvote my answer :) Happy coding